# Netbeans debugger not stopping at breakpoints

Tags: c, debugging, netbeans

I am on an Ubuntu 12.04 vm running netbeans 8.0.2

I am trying to debug a c project in netbeans and the deubgger does not stop at breakpoints. It does stop on breakpoints for other c projects just not this one. It is a multi-threaded project so maybe this has to do with it, although it seems that netbeans can debug multi-threaded projects.

One thing that might have to do with the issue is that I have to run netbeans with sudo in order to compile the project. If I don't do that I get this error:

```
flowop.c:1374:1: fatal error: opening dependency file .deps/flowop.Tpo: Permission denied
```

Any advice on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: Running netbeans with sudo is fine.. I just want ot be able to debug the project